# Angular TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined when using event.target.file[0]

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase-storage

I'm currently trying to take a file input from a user and store it to Firebase Storage using AngularFire. Since it's undefined, I'm convinced that whatever file they're looking at, it's NULL, but my UI clearly shows that I'm successfully inputting a file, but the error gets caught as soon as I select the file. Am I misunderstanding how the input sends information to my TypeScript file?

Here's my TS file:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { SubmitPostService } from './submit-post.service';
import { Post } from '../post.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-creation',
  templateUrl: './post-creation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-creation.component.scss']
})
export class PostCreationComponent implements OnInit {

  private uuidv4 = require('uuid/v4');

  // Main task
  task: AngularFireUploadTask;

  // Progress Monitoring
  percentage: Observable<number>;

  // Download URL
  downloadURL: Observable<string>;

  myForm: FormGroup;
  post: Post;
  ref: AngularFireStorageReference;
  files: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private postService: SubmitPostService,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      title: ['', [Validators.required]],
      artists: ['', [Validators.required]],
      description: '',
      medium: ''
    });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.post = new Post(
      this.uuidv4(),
      this.myForm.get('artists').value,
      this.myForm.get('title').value,
      new Date(),
      new Date(),
      `images/${Date.now()}_${this.myForm.get('title').value}`,
      this.myForm.get('description').value,
      this.myForm.get('medium').value
      );
    this.postService.submitPost(this.post);
  }

  upload(event: any) {
    console.log('Upload successful');
    try {
      const file = event.target.file[0];

      // The storage path
      const path = `images/${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;

      // Reference to storage bucket
      this.ref = this.storage.ref(path);

      // Main Task
      this.task = this.ref.put(file);

      // Tracks progress
      this.percentage = this.task.percentageChanges();

      this.percentage = this.task.snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(s => (s.bytesTransferred / s.totalBytes) * 100));

      this.downloadURL = this.ref.getDownloadURL();

    } catch (err) { console.log(err); }

    }

}
```

Here's my HTML:

```
  <div>
    <div class="progress">
      <progress max="100" [value]="(percentage | async)"></progress>
    </div>
    <h1>Post Creation</h1>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title">
      </mat-form-field>

      <br>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Artists" formControlName="artists">
      </mat-form-field>

      <br>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Description" formControlName="description">
      </mat-form-field>

      <br>

      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Medium" formControlName="medium">
      </mat-form-field>

      <br>

      <input type="file" (change)="upload($event)" accept=".png,.jpg">

      <br>
      <br>

      <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="myForm.invalid" color="primary">Submit Post</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

I've successfully created the Post objects in the Firestore, so it's not an issue of my firebase configs aren't correctly initialize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your upload method, in the `const file = event.target.file[0];` statement, the `file` property should be plural

Comment: You were right. Thank you for taking the time to look through my code. I appreciate it. c: